# Axis2 with SharePoint 2013 (ADFS / FedAuth cookie)

Tags: java, sharepoint, apache-axis, adfs

I'm very new to Axis2 and hope to get some help here. I searched for a long time but couldn't find an answer so far.
Currently I have to maintain a Java backend component which connects to SharePoint using Axis2. The latest task is to connect to a SharePoint 2013 which uses ADFS (a FedAuth cookie) to authenticate users. This FedAuth cookie is obtained from an identity provider which uses (as far as I know) NTLM for authentication. Could anyone give me a hint of how to obtain that FedAuth cookie and use it with the SharePoint stub objects (Lists, Webs, Copy) created with Axis2. If you need any further information I will try to provide these as soon as possible. Thanks!

Bjoern

Comment: Can you post your code? I suspect this may be down to a missing syntax in your connection method

Comment: I am at the same spot as you, what I have found it that you should perhaps be able to get it using <site-url>/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx, but that requires a Claims Provider (which seems to require some code on the SharePoint side)